# Marketing Cloud - How to check Open-Tracking data

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

When we send a Marketing Cloud email to all campaign-members of a campaign in salesforce, how we can track that how many campaign member opened that email?

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted so others can easily see this has been resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the below open tracking snippet in your email:

```html
<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking" />
```

If this has been done, you can check the tracking results in Email Studio like this:

1. Click the Tracking tab
2. Select the folder where the email you want to view is stored
3. Click the name of the email in the tracking workspace.

To view individual subscribers (including the subscriber key, email address and open time) you can click on the number of unique opens.

For an automated way to use the open information you can use an SQL query on the _Click Data View using a SQL query activity in Automation Studio (see ["Data View: Open" documentation article](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_open/))

**Related documentation:**

- [View Tracking Results for an Email Send](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/tracking/view_tracking_results_for_an_email_send/)
- [Data View: Open](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_open/)